# Word for someone who “really likes and pays close attention to symmetry”

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I was thinking of *meticulous*, but is there any word that is specific to being meticulous with the symmetry of things?

> I am very ________ because I pay very close attention to symmetry.

Alternatively, the example sentence could be better phrased as

> People call me a ________ because I enjoy symmetry and pay close attention to it. Asymmetrical words do not bring me despair.

Comment: Yeah, it's called OCD.

Comment: @Ricky OCD is mental disorder which is  characterised as having repetitive behaviours _to the point of it being detrimental to one's life_. Merely being attentive/meticulous/whatever word OP is looking for, does not make one as having OCD.

Comment: In what way do you pay attention to it - are you an artist? -- an architect? -- a compulsive tidier? Do you create symmetry or merely notice it? Please can you give some context. Thanks.

Comment: @dwjohnston With all due respect (really), I'm rather well-placed to talk about these things: I'm married to someone with OCD, and the whole damn house is symmetrical, and I get yelled at each time my activities threaten to disrupt what appears to her to be the natural order of things. I'm not going to go into detail; suffice it to say that very close attention is paid to the way shoes, books, and cushions are positioned.

Comment: But would someone with a name like JuanPotato be likely to suffer from OCD?  (just asking)

Comment: Maybe not, but someone must have asked him to pose the question on their behalf. OCD people are terribly shy sometimes. Unless of course the picture frame is not quite perpendicular to the architrave; or someone has been deliberately and maliciously pawing their toothbrush and now it's facing the wrong way.

Comment: @Ricky  I can relate to your observations about people with obsessions about symmetry.  However I note that the OP's question title was **'Word for someone who really likes and pays close attention to symmetry'**.  I feel that the example sentence the OP used has pushed us in a certain direction because using _'very'_ in the example closes down some possible word candidates. Consider:

OP's:  _Ex: I am very *word* because I pay very close attention to symmetry._
   
Variant: _People call me a(n) *word* because I pay very close attention to symmetry._

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I pay attention to it in because it pleases me. I'm not a compulsive tidier, an architect, but maybe a bit of an artist. I just really enjoy when things are symmetrical and will try to make them so.

Comment: @Ricky I do not think OCD would be what I am looking for. It doesn't feel compulsive or a disorder.

Comment: People call me "Jony Ive"

Comment: I'd call you _Poirot_, but I fear many would miss the reference these days…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Yes, I was about to suggest that Agatha Christie's Hercule Poirot was known for being a bit anal about symmetry.  It may be that in some of Christie's works there are words to describe this proclivity.

Comment: @Ricky Far be it from me to gainsay your experience, but I think your words "natural order" may make the better descriptor than *symmetric*.  I would guess that there are many symmetric reorderings of your household artifacts that would not be acceptable to your spouse.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Thanks - your latest edit noted and appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there's a word, "[symmetrist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Symmetrist)," defined as someone "eminently studious of symmetry of parts."

Comment: And presumably _'asymmetrist'_ !  This word (and all of its variants) seems to inhabit a very deep and cavernous rabbit hole, and one apparently with few visitors from above.  Although the dictionary definition points away from the sense that the OP was using, _'symmetrist'_ could be redefined to take on that sense.  After all, 'common usage' is whatever we want to make it.  _'Symmetrist'_ **IS** a beautiful word.   Up-voted.

Comment: Actually the OED supports _'Symmetrist'_ in the sense of the original question: 

Oxford English Dictionary  
symmetrist symmetristrare—1  
(ˈsɪmɪtrɪst)  
[f. symmetry + -ist.]  
An **advocate of**, or one studious of, symmetry.  
_1624 Wotton Archit. in Reliq. (1672) 56 Some exact Symmetrists have been blamed for being too true. 1656 Blount Glossogr., Symmetrist or Symmetrian..one that considers the due proportion of a thing, and how well the parts agree with the whole; one skilled in proportions._

My highlight in the text quoted.  And It has a long usage! A Bounty is coming your way...

Comment: Thanks.  And I seem to think the original question asked for a noun, but I could be mistaken.  EDIT: I am mistaken.  I guess the title suggests the OP was looking for a noun.

Comment: @JohnMack, one should be careful when consulting the OED online: there is a red warning on the right side that tells you that the entry has not been updated since publication (over a century ago). At that time that headword was  considered "*rare*" and in the updated editions (in SOED-form) it has been dropped altogether. In [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=symmetrist&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) it is not found; neither it is in M-W. Its meaning, anyway, is/was different i.e.: "*an expert, studious of symmetry*".

Comment: @frank  Indeed.  I have a print version of the OED.  They are there in my profile picture if you look carefully.  I copy text from the online version because it save me typing.  I don't worry too much about references to obscure or archaic.  If we're talking about a word here it is 'alive'.  By some accounts I am archaic (and obscure), but for the moment very much alive.  The key reference for me was _'an advocate of'_, which is in the OED entry.  Cheers, John Mack

Comment: @JohnMack, makes no difference if OED is online or in print, it is over a century-old , they never bothered to make an updated edition, they are only revising a few entry at a time on the online version. If you want to know if a word exists now, you have to buy the current edition of SOED. I hope it is clear now.  Anyway, the point I was making is that even if it were still in use it is useless here. A scholar of something mustn't necessarily pay attention or be fastidious to that feature: an expert /studious of Egyptian temples may not pay himself attention to symmetry in real life.

Comment: @frank.  I acknowledge the point you are making, and concede the ground to you.

Answer (score 8):

Well there is a word in the dictionary for the opposite of a person who likes or pays attention to symmetry, as the Oxford English Dictionary has it:

> symmetrophobia
>   (ˌsɪmɪtrəʊˈfəʊbɪə)
>   Also symmetriphobia.
>   [irreg. f. symmetry + -o + -phobia.  ]
>   Dread or avoidance of symmetry, as shown or supposed to be shown in Egyptian temples, Japanese art, etc.
>   *1809 W. R. Hamilton Remarks Turkey i. 131 Another instance of the Symmetrophobia of the architects of antient Egypt is visible in the difference of the spaces between the sphinxes and crio-sphinxes. 1865 J. Fergusson Hist. Archit. i. iv. I. 103 The buildings..are..generally affected with a symmetriphobia that it is difficult to understand. 1881 R. S. Poole in Contemp. Rev. Sept. 373 Symmetrophobia, shown in the placing columns of different orders opposite one another, and a colonnade on one side only of a court. 1894 Lockyer Dawn Astron. viii. 75 At Karnak..we can see how closely the walls reflect the orientation of the included temples, even when they seem most liable to the suggestion of symmetrophobia.*

Although it is not explained in the above definition, the suffix *'-phobia'* modifies the main word so as to imply a fear or strong aversion.

It is interesting that there is apparently no clear preference for spelling in these words between *symmetro-* and *symmetri-*.  This might warrant a question in it's own right, but I will continue to use both versions in this discussion.

One might reasonably conclude from this that either ***'Symmetrophilia'*** or ***'Symmetriphilia'*** could be legitimate words describing an inclination towards or a taste for symmetry.  The Greek suffix *'-philia'* implies *'like'* or *'love'* in relation to the word it modifies.

Following this some logic, a person who was pleased by or inclined to maintain symmetry might be called a ***'symmetrophile'*** or ***'symmetriphile'***.  In these cases the Greek suffix *'-phile'* suggests a person or thing that *'likes'* or *'loves'* the condition described by the word being modified.

A person who had an obsession with creating and/or maintaining symmetry might be called a ***'symmetrophiliac'*** or ***'symmetriphiliac'***.  Although there is no 'hard-and-fast' rule, the Greek suffix '-philiac' is usually used to indicate a more extreme attraction (or medically classifiable relationship) of a person (but not thing) to the condition described by the word being modified.

***'Symmetry'*** is an absolute term (it either exists or it does not), and it has a word for its opposite state, ***'assymmetry'***.  This creates a class of words for affection, obsession, or aversion to the opposite of symmetry.  Thus, a person who was an ***'asymmetrophobe'*** would be the same as a ***'symmetrophile'***.

The table below shows the relationship between most of the variations of the words.  The 'bolded' versions in the 'Word' columns have entries in standard dictionaries.  The others do not appear in dictionaries, and are mentioned only very rarely (http://writeworld.org/philiaquirks) or at all on the internet.

[image]

Note that an 'answer' to the OP's question is in the highlighted boxes in the table.

We can use Google's Ngram analytics to examine the frequency with which variations on these words occur in books between 1500 and 2008.  Firstly using the _'symmetro-' spelling:

[image]

Google's Ngram analytics returned no results for the _'symmetri-' spelling of these words.  Those familiar with Ngrams will know that the results should be treated with some caution - for instance *'symmetriphobia'* appears in the Oxford English Dictionary as we have seen in the extract quoted at the beginning of this answer.

A related concept is *'koinophilia'* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koinophilia) which describes a preference for appearances or arrangements which are deemed to be 'usual' as opposed to 'unusual'.  In biology, symmetry in bodily features is a frequently postulated to be a significant factor in mate selection.  Furthermore, there are suggestions that symmetry is a fundamental characteristic of nature, and to whatever extent this is true,  symmetrophilia might be considered a subset of koinophilia.  But assumptions about our preference for symmetry, or our ability to see it in nature are challenged in this article: http://www.livescience.com/4002-symmetry-nature-fundamental-fact-human-bias.html.

One is left to speculate that the absence of a word to specifically describe a preference for symmetry might reflect a human bias towards symmetry and a general view that it, and a preference for it, is perfectly natural, and not requiring a special word.  On this same consideration, an aversion to symmetry would be considered unusual and deserving of a word to describe that state, such as *'symmetrophobia'*, first recorded from 1809 in the OED.

The assistance of Stack Exchange EL&A members in developing an answer to this question - particularly Graffito - is acknowledged and appreciated.

Comment: @ JohnMack - I would suggest an edit to your answer to also include "assymetrophobia" and eventually "assymetrophobic(phobiac)".

Comment: @Graffito - Well if I can attribute the thought, and the cascade of further thoughts (-phobe, -phobic, -phile, -philiac, etc) you just opened up in my mind, to you.  Thanks,... I think....

Comment: Though it doesn't fit my thought perfectly, it's the best answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This term fits better in the previous example:

> I am very into *[feng shui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feng_shui)*. I pay very close attention to symmetry.

An interior decorator that knows what they're doing, doesn't have to make everything *look* symmetrical, it has to *feel* symmetrical. It has to be balanced, properly using *qi* while applying *feng shui.* It has to flow.

> Feng shui is one of the Five Arts of Chinese Metaphysics, classified as [physiognomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physiognomy) (observation of appearances through formulas and calculations). The feng shui practice discusses architecture in metaphoric terms of "invisible forces" that bind the universe, earth, and humanity together, known as *qi*.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the negative connotations, try **symmetry-minded**:

> I am very *symmetry-minded* because I pay very close attention to symmetry.

Example:

> I kinda like the recycled castle. Definitely more than Boxington.
>
> That said, I like the stone castle most, so I'm glad that's the one
>   that doesn't require donuts.
>
> **For the symmetry minded of us**, though, I should point out that Boxington DOES **line up nicely**.

(From a [forum post on design](http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/15/10152117.page).)

Answer (score -1):

I like the obsessive-compulsive answer. However, I think rephrasing could solve your dilemma.
"Symmetrical things gratify me. The corners, the lines, the edges--exact dimensions bring me pleasure. On the other hand, asymmetry leads me to despair."